# Manage automated email notifications at specific intervals for customer renewal letters

Tags: lightning

In the 3PL industry, we have to manage LOA's (Letters of Authority) with each customer for multiple railroads.  We would like to know if something like this could be managed in SF with regards to automated emails to the customer representative when we hit 60/30/15 days of the expiration. There would be 8 expirations dates under each customer, one for each railroad.  Once the cusotmer renews the letter and the date is changed in SF, the email for that railroad would no longer be executed.  Thank you for any suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Workflows for that. Take a look to this [link](https://inspireplanner.com/blog/use-salesforce-to-send-emails-quicker-than-ever-before/)

Also, search the web for Workflows in Salesforce.

Comment: Thank you Carlos.  I will review the link and give it a try.  I appreciate your feedback.